# sqlalchemy redefining operator

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to derive a class MyFraction from String in sqlalchemy and to override the operators so that the strings are sorted like fractions.

The code below fails (I realize that self is the comparator factory), but I'm not sure how to get it to work:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from fractions import Fraction

class MyFraction(String):
  class comparator_factory(String.Comparator):
    def __eq__(self, other) :
      return Fraction(self) == Fraction(other)
    def __ne__(self, other) :
      return Fraction(self) != Fraction(other)
    def __gt__(self, other) :
      return Fraction(self) > Fraction(other)
    def __lt__(self, other) :
      return Fraction(self) < Fraction(other)
```

From the documentation on sqlalchemy (http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/types.html#redefining-and-creating-new-operators), it is difficult to know how this should be done (there is something about an op called "goofy" but I have difficulty understanding how that relates to the problem above).

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the answer to my own question. SQLAlchemy is sending these instructions to some sql backend, so they are working directly on the representation of the value (in this case, a string) in the backend.  The equality operation, when redefined, can coerce `other` to be a string from a fraction and then perform an sql equality operation between strings. However, the comparator is not performing the operations itself.